# VMware Workstation 10.0.3 on Debian Wheezy compile error

Tags: debian, patch

I am trying to run VMware Workstation 10.0.3 on Debian Wheezy with RHEL custom kernel 3.10.0-4.
Installation went fine but when I try to: vmware-modconfig --console --install-all  I get the following error:

> Stopping VMware services:
>      VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
>      VM communication interface socket family                            done
>      Virtual machine communication interface                             done
>      Virtual machine monitor                                             done
>      Blocking file system                                                done
>   Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
>   make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only'
>   /usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-4-pve/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
>             MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
>   make[1]: Entering directory`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.0-4-pve'
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/common/task.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
>   /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1342:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
>     LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
>     Building modules, stage 2.
>     MODPOST 1 modules
>     CC      /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
>     LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.0-4-pve'
>   /usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
>             MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
>   make[1]: Entering directory`/tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only'
>   make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only'
>   cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
>   make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmmon-only'
>   Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
>   make: Entering directory`/tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only'
>   /usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-4-pve/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
>             MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
>   make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.0-4-pve'
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/driver.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/hub.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/userif.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/netif.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/bridge.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/filter.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/procfs.o
>     CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
>   /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/filter.c: In function ‘VNetFilterHookFn’:
>   /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/filter.c:262:16: error: ‘hooknum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   /tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/filter.c:262:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
>   make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only/filter.o] Error 1
>   make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only] Error 2
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.0-4-pve'
>   make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
>   make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-Df4vT2/vmnet-only'
>   Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.

Tried applying several patches i found but no one worked for me.
Is there a solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: Realize that vmtools will not necessarily compile on the latest releases of Linux.  This requires that VMWARE update their tools.  Second, are you absolutely sure that you have all prereq packages for kernel compilation installed?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.Yes, I realize that and already have all pre-req packages for kernel compilation..I've just found the solution: 1. cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source  2. cp vmnet.tar vmnet.tar.bak 3. tar xvf vmnet.tar 4. vi vmnet-only/filter.c 5. Replace all entries with #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 13, 0)  to #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 10, 0) 6. tar uvf vmnet.tar vmnet-only 7. rm -r vmnet-only 8. vmware-modconfig --console --install-all